# ExtJs 4 - Adding New Tab if does not exist and list data on grid

Tags: tabs, grid, extjs4

I use Ext Js 4 and there is a tabpanel and tabs inside it. I have managed to add new tab and prevent from adding the same tab if it is already opened. Anyhow, the data is listed after first opening, but cannot be listed after reopening. I think there is a problem with Ext Js 4 related to listing data on datagrid. Could you give a suggestion and sample regarding to this issue please? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Although @Geronimo could well be on track here, it would really help to see some code, specifically the section that shows how you create your store and the tabs. It could also be that you are using configs rather than InitComponent(), but there is no way to tell without seeing some code. Also, are you using 4.07 or 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it sounds like you have a `gridpanel` inside of a `tabpanel`:

> Anyhow, the data is listed after first opening, but cannot be listed
>   after reopening. I think there is a problem with Ext Js 4 related to
>   listing data on datagrid.

When you first open your tab the `gridpanel` has data in it, then when you close it and reopen it there is no data. Correct me if I have this wrong.

That would be normal ExtJS behavior if you are creating the `datastore` for your `gridpanel` separate from the code that creates the `gridpanel`.

When you close your `gridpanel` tab (destroying it), it will also destroy the store that holds the data for it.

There are a few solutions, you can give your store a `storeId` config which will register it with `StoreManager` and keep it from getting destroyed when a component is destroyed. Using this method you can also configure your `gridpanel` with the store like this:

```
// other grid configs...
store: Ext.StoreManager.lookup('yourStoreId'),
// other grid configs...
```

That method will *not* reload the store data when you create a new `gridpanel` tab. If you actually want the store to load new data whenever you create a new tab you should simply include your store creation code - `Ext.create(Ext.data.Store, { //etc..` (or however you are doing it) with the same code that is creating the `gridpanel` tab.

With that second method, your `gridpanel` will continue to destroy its `datastore` whenever it closes - the way it is doing now, but you will recreate and reload the store whenever you create a new tab so it will not be a problem.

I think there is also a config somewhere that lets you specify if you want the `gridpanel` to destroy the store when it is destroyed itself.

I usually use the first method however, then I destroy the store manually when I really don't need it anymore. Or reload the data manually when I want that. It helps cut down on unnecessary Ajax requests on the server.

Comment: Thanks for good explanations. You are right, but I think every time tab is opened in tabpanel, we should connect the database and select the records as the records may be changed commonly. I think the problem is related to getUpdater() method of Ext.tab.Panel. We were using that method before, but by the release of ExtJs4, I do not know which method performs its job. Could you give an example please what changes has to be made in order to transform these code to ExtJs4.1? Thanks in advance...

Comment: var updater =tab.getUpdater();
        updater.on('beforeupdate', function (x, y, z) {/**/});
        updater.on('update', function (x, y) {/**/});
        updater.update(menu.targetUrl);
        tab.setTitle('any title');

Comment: I'm going to have to with @Izhaki on this one, can you edit your question and post the code that you use to create your tab inside of it?